# UISearchBar in TableViewController moves up after segue and changing rotation

Tags: ios, swift

I have master-detail application, where I use `UISearchController` to filter cells in `UITableViewController` (master). I have problem with disappearing `UISearchBar` after segue. Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Run app in portrait mode
2. Touch SearchBar and type search query
3. Touch one of the cells in TableView and segue to detail controller
4. While in detail controller, change orientation of the device to landscape mode
5. Segue back to master. Now SearchBar is partially hidden behind Navigation Bar, even after chaning orientation back to portrait.

My Master controller's MWE:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var data = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
    var searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureSearchController()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.collapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Search Controller

    private func configureSearchController() {
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let content = data[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.text = content
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let content = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = content
        return cell
    }

}
```

Screenshots:

[image: Initial state of master controller][image: Master Controller after changing rotation and segueing back][image: Master Controller after changing rotation and segueing back]

Comment: This is due to when application Segue back to master after the orientation. Your mater view getting wrong Navigation Bas height. Due to which it get pushed under the navigation bar. 
I think try printing the navigation bar height and call your `configureSearchController()` .

Comment: I made a little 'investigation' and it looks like a bug in UISeachController/UITableViewController. Whole frame of table view is not properly setted after segueing back. This bug is also present in this example from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html. Here, after segueing back search bar overlaps the status bar (because in this example option `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` is set to true, in my MWE is set to false).